# Changing template arguments at runtime c++

Tags: c++, templates

I have a large and complex program that makes use of templates quite extensively.
For the sake of simplicity, consider I have the following classes in my program:

**BronzeFork , SilverFork, GoldFork**

**SimpleKnife , SerratedKnife, ButterKnife**

**RedSpoon , GreenSpoon, BlueSpoon**

and then in main.cpp I call a function:

```
Eating<BronzeFork, SerratedKnife, BlueSpoon>::runEat();
```

My aim is to be able to be able to feed arguments at runtime to my (compiled) program in order to modify the kind of fork or spoon that I want in this run.

I could do it with a very large switch statement running every combination of forks, knives and spoons but it seems quite messy, convoluted and hard to maintain.
Especially because I am continuously adding kinds of Forks, Knifes and Spoons into the program.

What would be the best way to do this in a clean, efficient way?

Comment: Don't use template parameters for stuff you need to vary at run time.

Comment: The templates are going to be compiled before you run the code. There's other ways to do this. In the end though, it depends on what the behaviour of the combinations should be. Say I throw in a new spoon, how do you want to define what it does?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what the end goal is here,but as a broad and high level guideline, templates don't seem to be the right tool for the job.
Templates are valuable because they're compile time and optimize the code at compile time and have no runtime overhead.

If you want to accomplish the same thing, but dynamically at runtime, use dynamic dispatch.

Comment: Having said that, it *is* possible to do without a very big switch statement (generate bunch of instantiations without having to list them explicitly). I will try to come up with some real easy example...

Comment: I think that you are right, templates may not be the ideal choice here. Can you point me to some resources that would help me transform my code in order to use dynamic dispatch?

Comment: You've not really given us enough to work with in terms of the design of the program. Using a non-templated Eating class that uses three virtual classes seems like a better choice and will allow for run time changes. I'm guessing the three classes have similar interfaces otherwise using them as template arguments would be tricky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not necessarily the best way to *solve your problem*. This is one way to generate a lot of instantiations in a compact manner. It may or may not suit your need.

I assume each of your classes have some kind of ID for run-time selection, say a string. So `BronzeFork::id` would be `"BronzeFork"`. I will use abbreviated names henceforth.

```
  #include <tuple>
  #include <string>
  #include <functional>
  #include <map>

  struct F1 { static constexpr const char* id = "F1"; };
  struct F2 { static constexpr const char* id = "F2"; };
  struct F3 { static constexpr const char* id = "F3"; };
  struct K1 { static constexpr const char* id = "K1"; };
  struct K2 { static constexpr const char* id = "K2"; };
  struct K3 { static constexpr const char* id = "K3"; };
  struct S1 { static constexpr const char* id = "K1"; };
  struct S2 { static constexpr const char* id = "K2"; };
  struct S3 { static constexpr const char* id = "K3"; };

  template <typename F, typename K, typename S> struct Eater
  {
      static void eat();
  };

  using t3 = std::tuple<std::string, std::string, std::string>;

  std::map<t3, std::function<void()>> funcMap;
```

Now we need to populate `funcMap`. We need nested compile-time loops. I implement them as separate templates using fold-expressions. There might be a better way, but this one is very unsophisticated and straightforward so it's easy to understand.

```
  template <typename F, typename K, typename S> struct populate0
  {
      void operator()() { funcMap.insert({{F::id, K::id, S::id}, Eater<F, K, S>::eat}); }
  };

  // Inner loop
  template <typename Fs, typename K, typename S> struct populate1;
  template <typename ... Fs, typename K, typename S>
  struct populate1 <std::tuple<Fs...>, K, S> // loop over Fs
  {
      void operator()() { (populate0<Fs, K, S>()(), ...); }
  };


  // Middle loop
  template <typename Fs, typename Ks, typename S> struct populate2;
  template <typename Fs, typename ... Ks, typename S>
  struct populate2 <Fs, std::tuple<Ks...>, S> // loop over Ks
  {
      void operator()() { (populate1<Fs, Ks, S>()(), ...); }
  };


  // Outer loop
  template <typename Fs, typename Ks, typename Ss> struct populate3;
  template <typename Fs, typename Ks, typename... Ss> // loop over Ss
  struct populate3 <Fs, Ks, std::tuple<Ss...>>
  {
      void operator()() { (populate2<Fs, Ks, Ss>()(), ...); }
  };
```

Now we need to just run the loop.

```
  populate3<std::tuple<F1, F2, F3>, 
            std::tuple<K1, K2, K3>, 
            std::tuple<S1, S2, S3>>()();
```

Whenever you add another class, add it to this call.

Answer (score 1):

C++ is a compilable language, meaning that the types must be known at code-generation-time. Virtual classes could be a solution to your case.

This is not incompatible with the use of templates, which can keep the source code compact. But all specializations with the types you can meet at run-time must be instantiated.

Comment: It has nothing to do with c++ being usually only be used as a compiled language ([cling](https://github.com/root-project/cling)  is an interactive C++ interpreter). It's because the specifications say that you can't use runtime values as template arguments.

Comment: @t.niese: this limitation is set so that the C++ code be compilable. I have rephrased.